# Are reboots required after updates?

Tags: kernel, updates, restart

I noticed from other posts that `/var/run/reboot-required.pkgs` tells what package is requiring a reboot, but this file does not exist anymore.

I have been running Ubuntu 13.10 (and updated to beta 14.04) and realized that my laptop has not asked me for a reboot once. That may be because I reboot it a few times a week already, but it has never even asked.

Back in the day, maybe around Ubuntu 10.04 I remember very vividly the red gear on the top right of gnome/unity requesting reboot, but this no longer happens.

Did the kernel update to not require these reboots anymore? How would that work?

Comment: Have you searched the file `reboot-required.pkgs` on other directory? It could also have changed the name or be working in another way that doesn't require that file.

Comment: I haven't found another place that it could be in yet.. but I'll look

Comment: There is no file on the hard drive named "reboot-required" (did a find) and that should include a result for .pkgs result too... but point being, this file does not exist. It may have been renamed, or migrated into another package, but it is not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red gear is gone, but after installing kernel updates, the update-manager will tell you to click here to reboot.

Comment: thank you, I usually do an apt-get update and dist-upgrade almost every day, so I usually beat the the update manager to it. I didn't look to see if update manager bugs about reboot, so that makes since. Thanks for looking :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, kernel upgrades will still require rebooting.

Comment: Could you expand the answer to provide the basis for your reasoning based on what is asked w.r.t. `/var/run/reboot-required.pkgs` not being present on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: @Aditya  - Who says 14.04 is no longer using `/var/run/reboot-required.pkgs` ? The OP never indicated she installed a packages that requires a reboot, so why presume there is a problem? If there is a problem, should be a bug report. The only things that require a reboot are 1. After installing a new kernel and 2. After installing (or removing) some kernel modules, such as nvidia or ati video drivers, some wireless cards as well. A reboot is required to load the new kernel into RAM. A reboot is often advised as it is easier then explaining how to restart services.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen OP mentions in the 1st para of the question that `/var/run/reboot-required.pkgs` doesn't exist anymore. And he said in 2nd para that he upgraded 13.10 to 14.04 beta and it didn't ask him for reboot -- upgrading implies that kernel was upgraded as well which requires reboot. I obviously don't know if it is a bug or something else.

Comment: @Aditylzheimer's dementia OP also mentions they have rebooted.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: OP mentions in 2nd para "*but it has never **even** asked.*" I am interpreting it as OP has just upgraded and it isn't asking him to reboot. I may be wrong in my interpretation but I think I am correct otherwise why would he ask this question.

Comment: @Aditya Your interpretation is wrong and you are not fully reading the OP question. Question is about multiple updates to kernel after having upgraded to 14.04 and rebooted multiple times already.

Comment: Yes I should reword that, it did ask for reboot on the upgrade of distributions, but not anymore after updates like kernel updates.

Comment: Not anymore as in notifications after updates.. I still reboot because its not the best battery